# Pythagoras theorem and linear independence

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

There is a proposition saying that $S=\lbrace v_1,v_2,...,v_n \rbrace $ is a set of non-nule ortogonals vectors that implies that is linear independence.

I prove that with the scalar product and the vector norm and is almost trivial i have and idea:

Is possible to prove that using and extended version of the Pythagoras theorem for the vector norm?

Answer (score 1):

Let $v_1,v_2,...,v_n$ be mutually orthogonal and suppose that

$0=c_1v_1+c_2v_2+...+c_nv_n, \quad c_i \in \mathbb{F}$.

By the Pythagorean theorem,

$0=\big|\big| \sum_1^{n}c_iv_i \big|\big|^2=\sum_1^{n}|c_i|^2||v_i||^2 \geq |c_j|^2||v_j||^2, \quad j=1,2,...,n$.

Conclude that $c_j=0$ for all $j=1,2,...,n$.